# Автоматическое запускание программ

Tags: python, файлы

Возможно ли сделать так , что бы после загрузки  файла  с кодом , программа сразу бы открывалась в терминале с помощью бат-файла и к примеру выводила "Hello world" .Главный вопрос - можно ли сделать файл авто-запускающимся,если да - то как?
Вот пример бат-файла:

```
WinRAR X ForStart *.py TheFinal\  (для разархивирования rar'a)
WinRAR X ForStart *.txt TheFinal\
WinRAR X ForStart *.bat TheFinal\
cd TheFinal
cd Code
python UnShifrVirus.py
python start.py
pause
```

Comment: Вы же тру-хакер, вы должны знать что в современных ОС нет дыры типа "скачался файл и тут же запустился".

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов Запишите это в ответ,ведь вы ответили на вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В современных ОС нет дыры типа "скачался файл и тут же запустился"